# Дополнение защиты VDS

Tags: debian, ddos

Здравствуйте.

Как правильно защититься от большинства типов DDoS-атак на VDS OVH?

Там идёт AntiDDoS Standart, который легко ложиться примерно 100к пакетами.

Answer (score 1):

Это наверно очевидный ответ, но купить защиту получше. В идеале отбивать ddos атаки должен сам провайдер, т.к у него есть для этого возможности. Если нужна защита для сайта, то можно использовать например cloudflare. Если приложение общается по udp, то тут немного сложнее. Например при udp flood атаке могут забить весь канал и будет абсолютно без разницы блокируешься у себя на vds его через iptables или нет. Можно например распределить систему на множество небольших vps  с разными ip. Это не спасет полностью от ddos, но усложнит жизнь неквалифицированным атакующим. Есть еще вариант с флудом, который antiddos защиты обычно пропускают, т.к его трудно отделить от обычного трафика. В этом случае достаточно просто заблокировать его на фаерволе.